# how to not get duplicate products in cart in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

so I'm building a shop in vue3 and now when I add a product to the cart it added, but if I add the same product again it shows twice(a "duplicate"). and I want it to have a increment and decrement so I will update the quantities of the product that way. how can I do that? when I try I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" How can I make it the way I want? Thanks in advance and the code is below:

btw, I'm using Vuex for state management. and the error is because of the count2 method in the cart.vue file.

shop.vue

```
<template>
    Cart Items: <cart-badge :count="cartLength">{{ count }}</cart-badge>
    <div class="shop">
        <div class="products" v-for="Product in products" :key="Product.id">
            <h1>{{ Product.name }}</h1> <img :src="Product.pic" width="400" /> <br>
            {{ Product.description }} <br>
            {{ "$" + Product.price }} <br>
            <button class="addToCart" @click="addToCart(Product)">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CartBadge from '../components/CartBadge.vue';

export default {
    name: 'shop',
    methods: {
        addToCart(Product) {
            this.$store.state.cart.push(Product)
            console.log(this.$store.state.cart)
        },
    },
    components: {
        'cart-badge': CartBadge
    },
    computed: {
        cartLength() {
            return this.$store.state.cart.length;
        },
        products() {
            return this.$store.state.Product;
        },
        cart() {
            return this.$store.state.cart;
        }
    },
    /*props: {
        count: Number
    }*/
}
</script>
```

db.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "iphone 11",
    "pic": "/pics/iphone11.jpg",
    "description": "newest iphone!",
    "price": 999,
    "qty": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "galaxy s22",
    "pic": "/pics/galaxy22.jpg",
    "description": "a new phone from samsung!",
    "price": 1200,
    "qty": 10
  }
]
```

cart.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>Cart</h1>
    <div class="cartItems">
        Cart Items: <cart-badge :count="cartLength">{{ count }}</cart-badge>
        <p v-if="!cart.length">Your cart is empty! please add something to the cart</p>
        <div class="products" v-for="Product in cart" :key="Product.id">name: {{ Product.name }} price: {{ Product.price
        }}</div>
        <button v-if="cart.length" class="removeFromCart" @click="removeFromCart(Product)">X</button>
        <button v-if="cart.length" class="increment" @click="count2(Product)">+</button>
        <button v-if="cart.length" class="descrement" @click="count--">-</button>
        <strong v-if="cart.length">Total ${{ cartSum }}</strong>
        <p>{{ count }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CartBadge from '../components/CartBadge.vue';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'Cart',
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    components: {
        'cart-badge': CartBadge
    },
    computed: {
        cartLength() {
            return this.$store.state.cart.length;
        },
        products() {
            return this.$store.state.Product;
        },
        cart() {
            return this.$store.state.cart;
        },
        ...mapGetters([
            "cartSum"
        ]),
        /*productsqty() {
            //Product.qty = Product.qty + 1
            return this.$store.state.Product.qty + 1
        }*/
    },
    methods: {
        removeFromCart(Product) {
            this.$store.state.cart.splice(Product)
            console.log(this.$store.state.cart)
        },
        count2(Product) {
            /*Product = this.$store.state.cart.push(Product)
            console.log(this.$store.state.cart.push(Product))*/
            //Product = this.$store.state.cart(Product)
            let FoundProduct = this.$store.state.cart.find(o => o.id === this.$store.state.cart.Product.id)
            if (FoundProduct) {
                FoundProduct.qty += 1;
                return;
            }
            //this.cart.id = Product.id
            //this.cart.push(this.cart.Product)
            this.$store.state.cart.Product.id = Product.id
            this.$store.state.cart.push(this.$store.state.cart.Product)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

store.js(vuex file for state management)

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import Product from "../db.json";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cart: [],
    Product,
  },
  getters: {
    cart: (state) => state.cart,
    cartSum: (state) => {
      return state.cart.reduce((total, Product) => {
        return (total += Product.price * 1);
      }, 0);
    },
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

Comment: In `addToCart()` method, instead of just blindly adding the product to the cart array (`this.$store.state.cart.push(Product)`), first search the array to see if the product already exists. If it product is already in the cart, then just increment the `qty` instead of inserting a second product.

Comment: @bassxzero thanks. how can i do that?

Comment: @bassxzero why did you deleted your answer? can you help me?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it wasn't using actions so it wasn't really a solution to your problem. Not to be that guy, but why are you using vuex with vue3 anyway? I'm pretty sure they are recommending Pinia now.